# Dynamically Move Entry Xamarin.Forms

Tags: ios, xamarin, keyboard, position, xamarin.forms

I have an entry field at the bottom of the screen in one of my projects. However, on iOS, when you click the entry field, the keyboard is displayed over top the entry field and obscures the vision of it. Therefore, people can't see what they're typing.

How can I solve this problem? Is there a way that I can move the entry field so it is displayed above the keyboard when in focus?

```
//NOTE: the entry field that needs to be moved is userEntry
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using System.Text;
using CloudClubv1._2_;
using Backend;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace FrontEnd
{
    public class ClubChatPage : ContentPage 
    {

        public static ObservableCollection<FrontComment> CurrentCommentsList;
        ObservableCollection<FrontComment> commentsList;
        ColorHandler ch;
        Entry userEntry;
        ParentFrontClub club;
        bool isMember;
        Image bBack, bSettings;
        public static ListView listView;
        TapGestureRecognizer settingsTgr, backButtonTgr;
        public ClubChatPage(ParentFrontClub club, List<DBItem> chatList, List<Account> commentUsers, List<Account> requestUsersList, bool isMember)
        {
            this.isMember = isMember;
            settingsTgr = new TapGestureRecognizer();
            settingsTgr.Tapped += SettingsTgr_Tapped;
            backButtonTgr = new TapGestureRecognizer();
            backButtonTgr.Tapped += BackButtonTgr_Tapped;
            this.club = club;
            ch = new ColorHandler();
            this.BackgroundColor = Color.Black;
            this.Title = club.Title;



            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
            this.commentsList = new ObservableCollection<FrontComment>();
            int clubRequestCount = 0;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(chatList.Count.ToString());
            chatList.Reverse();
            for (int i = 0; i < chatList.Count; i++)
            {
                if (chatList[i].GetType() == typeof(Comment))
                {
                    if (commentUsers[i] != null)
                    {
                        this.commentsList.Add(new FrontComment((Comment)chatList[i], commentUsers[i - clubRequestCount]));

                    }
                }
                else if (chatList[i].GetType() == typeof(ClubRequest))
                {
                    this.commentsList.Add(new FrontComment((ClubRequest)chatList[i], requestUsersList[clubRequestCount], this.isMember));
                    clubRequestCount++;

                }
            }
            CurrentCommentsList = this.commentsList;

            updatePage();



        }



        private void updatePage()
        {

            bBack = new Image
            {
                Source = FileImageSource.FromFile("arrow_back.png"),
                WidthRequest=30,
               // Scale = ,

                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                HeightRequest = 30,
                Aspect = Aspect.AspectFill
            };
            bBack.GestureRecognizers.Add(backButtonTgr);

            var actionBarLabel = new Label
            {
                Text = this.club.Title,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                TextColor = ch.fromStringToColor("white"),
                FontSize = 22,
                FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold
            };
             bSettings = new Image
            {
                Source = ImageSource.FromFile("settings.png"),
                Scale = .8,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
            };
            bSettings.GestureRecognizers.Add(settingsTgr);


            var actionBarLayout = new StackLayout
            {
                Children =
                {
                    bBack,
                    actionBarLabel,
                    bSettings
                },
                HeightRequest= 30,
                Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                BackgroundColor = ch.fromStringToColor(this.club.clubColor),
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                Padding = new Thickness(10,10,0,10)
            };

            listView = new ListView
            {
                ItemsSource = CurrentCommentsList,
                ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(CommentViewCell)),
                HasUnevenRows = true,
                SeparatorVisibility = SeparatorVisibility.None,
                SeparatorColor = ch.fromStringToColor("white"),
                BackgroundColor = ch.fromStringToColor("white")                

            };
            if (CurrentCommentsList.Count != 0) {
                listView.ScrollTo (CurrentCommentsList [CurrentCommentsList.Count () - 1], ScrollToPosition.End, false);
            }
            listView.ItemTapped += ListView_ItemTapped;

            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<CommentViewCell, FrontComment>(this, "hi", async (sender, args) =>
            {
                var comment = (FrontComment)args;
                var answer = await DisplayAlert("Report User", "Do you really want to report " + comment.AuthorUsername + "?", "Yes", "No");
                if (answer)
                {
                    await App.dbWrapper.CreateBan(comment.AuthorId, comment.Id, App.dbWrapper.GetUser().Id);
                    comment.ShowReport = false;
                    comment.UpdateProperty("ShowReport");

                }
                else
                {

                }

                //updatePage();

            });


            userEntry = new Entry
            {
                BackgroundColor = ch.fromStringToColor("white"),
                TextColor = ch.fromStringToColor("black"),
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.End,
                IsEnabled = isMember,
                Placeholder = "Tap to chat"
            };
            userEntry.Completed += UserEntry_Completed;
            userEntry.Focused += UserEntry_Focused;
            Label lEmptyChat = new Label
            {
                Text = "There are no messages. Type below!",
                FontSize = 38,
                TextColor = ch.fromStringToColor("black"),
                XAlign = TextAlignment.Center,
                YAlign = TextAlignment.Center,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand

            };
            if (CurrentCommentsList.Count != 0)
            {
                Content = new StackLayout
                {
                    Children =
                {
                   actionBarLayout,
                    listView,
                    userEntry
                },
                    BackgroundColor = ch.fromStringToColor("lightGray"),
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
                };
            }
            else
            {
                Content = new StackLayout
                {
                    Children =
                    {
                        actionBarLayout,
                        lEmptyChat,
                        userEntry
                    },
                    BackgroundColor = ch.fromStringToColor("lightGray"),
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
                };
            }
        }

        private void UserEntry_Focused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void ListView_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {
            var item = (FrontComment)e.Item;
            for(int i = 0; i < CurrentCommentsList.Count; i++)
            {
                if (CurrentCommentsList[i].ShowReport==true)
                {
                    CurrentCommentsList[i].ShowReport = false;
                    CurrentCommentsList[i].UpdateProperty("ShowReport");
                }

            }
            for (int i = 0; i < CurrentCommentsList.Count; i++)
            {
                if (CurrentCommentsList[i].Id == item.Id && CurrentCommentsList[i].ClubRequestBool == false)
                {
                    CurrentCommentsList[i].ShowReport = true;
                    CurrentCommentsList[i].UpdateProperty("ShowReport");
                }

            }

         //   updatePage();

        }


        private async void UserEntry_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (userEntry.Text != "")
            {
               // var joinClub = await App.dbWrapper.JoinClub(club.Id);
                var commentOutput = await App.dbWrapper.CreateComment(userEntry.Text, club.Id);
                //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("OUTPUT: "+joinClub);
                userEntry.Text = "";
                listView.ScrollTo(CurrentCommentsList[CurrentCommentsList.Count() - 1], ScrollToPosition.End, false);

                //  updatePage();
            }


        }
        private async void BackButtonTgr_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            await App.dbWrapper.RemoveCurrentClubId();
            var btn = sender as Image;
            btn.IsEnabled = false;
            await Navigation.PopAsync();
            btn.IsEnabled = true;
        }
        private async void SettingsTgr_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //var btn = sender as TapGestureRecognizer;
            //btn.Tapped -= SettingsTgr_Tapped;
         //   bSettings.GestureRecognizers.Remove(settingsTgr);
            var tagsList = await App.dbWrapper.GetTags(club.Id);
            var usersList = await App.dbWrapper.GetClubMembers(club.Id);
            var frontClubMemberList = new List<FrontClubMember>();
            var isMember = await App.dbWrapper.IsMember(club.Id);
            var founderAccount = await App.dbWrapper.GetAccount(club.founderId);
            var prevRating = await App.dbWrapper.GetUserRating(club.Id);
            var myFriendRequests = await App.dbWrapper.GetFriendRequests();
            for (int i = 0; i < usersList.Count; i++)
            {
                var storedFriendship = await App.dbWrapper.GetFriendship(usersList[i].Id);

                if(storedFriendship == 1) //Indicates request was sent from either user
                {
                    //  var accReq = App.dbWrapper.GetAccountFriendRequests(usersList[i].Id);
                    storedFriendship = 3;
                    var accReq = new List<FriendRequest>();
                    for (int j = 0; j < myFriendRequests.Count; j++)
                    {
                        if (myFriendRequests[j].AuthorId == usersList[i].Id)
                        {
                            storedFriendship = 1;//indicates request was sent by other acc
                        }

                     }


                }
                if (usersList[i].Id == App.dbWrapper.GetUser().Id) storedFriendship= 4;

                frontClubMemberList.Add(new FrontClubMember(usersList[i], storedFriendship));



            }
            var btn = sender as Image;
            btn.GestureRecognizers.Remove(settingsTgr);
            btn.InputTransparent = true;
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new ChatInfoPage(tagsList, club, frontClubMemberList, isMember, founderAccount.Username, prevRating));
            btn.GestureRecognizers.Add(settingsTgr);
            btn.InputTransparent = false;
        }

        //used by backend push notifications to scroll to new comments
        public static void ScrollToCurrent(){
            listView.ScrollTo(CurrentCommentsList[CurrentCommentsList.Count() - 1], ScrollToPosition.End, false);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply wrap the content in a ScrollView - this will allow the Entry fields to be moved when the Keyboard appears.

Comment: +1 scrollviews should almost always be used in data entry forms, even if on your test device there is no need to scroll. unless you test every single target device in every orientation, you probably need a scrollview

Comment: +1 Using ScrollViews has worked for me. Discussion on Xamarin Forums also suggests to use ScrollViews. Information in this topic ( https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/27383/keyboard-hides-input-in-xamarin-forms ) may be useful.